# Find an orthogonal basis for the orthogonal complement of $sp([1, -1, 3])$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an orthogonal basis for the orthogonal complement of $Wsp([1, -1, 3])$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$

This is my solution:

First, I computed the orthogonal complement of $(sp([1, -1, 3]))^{\perp}$:

$\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} s - 3t \\ s \\ t\end{bmatrix}$

which is equals to (for some $s$ and $t$): $W^{\perp}=\{[1, 1, 0], [-3, 0, 1]\}$

Second, by applying the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to compute the orthogonal basis:

$\vec{v_{1}}=\vec{w_{1}^{\perp}}=[1, 1, 0]$

$\vec{v_{2}}=\vec{w_{2}^{\perp}}-\bigg(\frac{\vec{w_{2}^{\perp}}\cdot \vec{v_{1}}}{\vec{v_{1}}\cdot \vec{v_{1}}}\vec{v_{1}} \bigg)=[-3, 3, 2]$

which is

$\{[1, 1, 0], [-3, 3, 2]\}$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. Now I will type extra stuff to meet the 15 character limit.

Comment: Looks correct to me.